# Passing path of document directory to xcode run scripts

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios5, xcode4.2

I want to pass the location of the documents (data) directory to the script which runs after the build in a xcode target.

What is the environment variable I should use?

Comment: I would have appreciated if the person who asked to close this (very legitimate) question had the decency to atleast add a comment as to why he feels this question is not useful.

Comment: AFAIK, there is not environment variable - since the path to the document directory is available only at runtime. What are you trying to accomplish?  (btw, that's a legit question IMO)

Comment: @CouchDeveloper Thanks for the reply. This is what I really wanna do. I want to grab a few resources created during the execution of my SenTests (these resources are stored in the documents directory) using Run Script and then process these once the tests are over. Hence I want to somehow get the path to the sandbox document directory in the scripts. Also, would be glad if you uprate this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the sandbox directory is created AFTER the build completes and the simulator starts, the environment has no knowledge at all of the documents (sandbox directory).
You can run a script in the background, which keeps checking the simulator's dump folder to see which directory was created immediately after the app was started.